# Can a company take my domain away from me?

Tags: domains, legal, domain-registration

I have a domain which coincidentally is the same name of a company. Is there any legal way in which this company can take my domain away from me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the name was trademarked before you registered it, or the name was in use and popular at the time of your purchase then trademarked later, then they can claim it and take it away from you. If the trademark was filed *after* you purchased the domain, and it was popular or in use, then as long as you don't use that domain in anyway that relates to them or their business they cannot take it away from you.

Comment: Ugh, that's too bad :( Thanks for the quick answer.